# Replace matrix elements by a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a Matrix M[n,m] `M=zeros(n,m)` . I want all the elements M(i,j)of that matrice to be an another Matrix K of size K[i,j*2]  filled randomly with [0 1] .
I have tried the following , but I didn't get any result

```
 system= zeros(20,20);
for i=1:20
    for j=1:20 
        system(i,j)=randi([0 1], i,j*2);
    end
end
```

Any solutions ? thanks.

Comment: [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Comment: how to add the random binary filling to this fonction ?

Comment: I don't understand your goal, but you probably should write: `randi(2,[i j*2])-1`

Comment: Also, change `zeros` to `cell`, and use `system{i,j}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following codes.

```
system= cell(20);
for i=1:20 
    for j=1:20 
        system{i,j}=randi([0 1], i,j*2); 
    end 
end 
system =cell2mat(system);
```